# If Select inside SQL IN statement returns NULL then select ALL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, prepared-statement

I'm trying to shorten my code and make it faster.
However, I am struggling a bit with this statement.
I want it to return **all** news if the value `page_category` is not set.

`page_category` is set in the DB as `1,2,3,4` and each news article has 1 category like below.

**Page Category**

[image: Page Category]

**News Category**

[image: news]

I want to fetch each news article that has the category id within `page_category`.

This is my statement, and it works fine for whenever `page_category` is set.

```
"AND n.news_category IN (SELECT page_category FROM pages WHERE page_name = :pagename AND page_deleted IS NULL)";
```

How can I rewrite this so that `n.news_category` does not count if return is `NULL`?

This is my whole current statement:

```
 $sql = "SELECT n.news_title, n.news_content, n.news_published_dt "
      . "FROM news n "
      . "LEFT JOIN languages l "
      . "ON n.news_lang = l.language_id "
      . "WHERE ((l.language_val = :language) OR (n.news_lang_all IS NOT NULL)) "
      . "AND n.news_deleted IS NULL "
      . "AND n.news_published = 1 "
      . "AND n.news_category IN (SELECT page_category FROM pages WHERE page_name = :pagename AND page_deleted IS NULL)";
```

Comment: Sample data might help clarify your question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff added a picture :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `page_category` takes on a `NULL` value and you want all rows in that case, then use `exists` instead:

```
EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM pages p
        WHERE p.page_name = :pagename AND p.page_deleted IS NULL AND
              (p.page_category is null or p.page_cateogry = n.news_category)
       )
```

Comment: Can I place this within the WHERE statement of another select statement? See updated question.

Comment: @GjertIngarGjersund . . . Yes, that is where an `EXISTS` expression typically goes, in the `WHERE` clause.